# Angular HttpClient Response Object doesn't contains headers which can be seen in the browsers network tab and as well as when I am using PostMan

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, http, jwt

This is the method doing Post call to the server

```
 submitData(credential){
    credential = JSON.stringify(credential);    
    return this._http.post("http://localhost:8080/login",credential,{observe: 'response'});
  }
```

Here I am logging the data in the console

```
this.jwtService.submitData(data)
    .subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);

    })
```

the response in the console I get

```
HttpResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/login", ok: true, …}
  headers: HttpHeaders
    normalizedNames: Map(0)
      [[Entries]]
        No properties
      size: 0
```

This is my browsers Network tab and **Authorization** header can be seen with its value

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJuYWNodSIsImV4cCI6MTU4NDg2MTYxOH0.Bh46Bv4YWou5kzNp2ib_14Xnu9Ob7G41QqY4_t6UzxdJiq-CHX1yk7BWBmHlOXygMuS7YNVNu0HkhnREoY69iQ
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 22 Mar 2020 06:20:18 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

[Even with the postman application, I get the same response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DaUu.png)

**I need a workaround for this problem.**

Comment: can you point out which header exactly is missing?

Comment: Authorization Header, The one which has Bearer token in it.

Comment: first of all - i cannot see any "subscribe" in you code, and (since observables are lazy) unless you put some subscription - request may not be fired at all

Comment: @happyZZR1400 I have already a subscribe in my component I will add that too in the Question, and I am logging the data there itself i.e after subscription.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question and I am sharing it in the hope that somebody gets benefited from that.

I modified my code a little bit,

1st we need to import **tap** operator from 'rxjs/operators' as

```
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators'
```

then use the pipe operator like below and you will get your header.

```
 submitData(credential){
    credential = JSON.stringify(credential);    
    return this._http.post("http://localhost:8080/login",credential,{observe: 'response'})
    .pipe(tap(res=>{
        console.log('response',res.headers.get('Authorization'));

    }))
  }
```

Make sure your server-side is having all the **CORS conditions** and **exposing the header you need**, for example, I needed Authorization header so I added following on my server-side (I am using spring-boot)

```
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Authorization")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.addCorsMappings(registry);
    }
```

**:) Happy Coding**

Comment: This doesn't work, at least for me. The object being passed from tap is the original observable, which in most cases a Json-deseiralized objectification of the message body, NOT the response message itself.